# Installation NDHpple to Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

When I try to build in terminal code:

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c release
```

I receive just error

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: 'build'
```

How install it to latest Xcode?

Comment: I suspect there is a space missing after `-I`

Comment: @vadian this documentation on github https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple , but I can't understand how add this file... I find it in /usr/lib , but don't know how build swift with it....

Comment: I try to add space - and error is same....

Comment: There are only 3 source files, you can just drag them into your project. Then  in build settings add `$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2` in `Header Search Paths` and `-lxml2` in `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: Are you using the Developer Snapshot?

Comment: @Abizern yes, I already update it

Comment: Do you get output for `swift build --version`?

Comment: I received  same: `no such file or directory: 'build'`

Comment: Which shows that you don't have the correct version installed. It's not the Swift 2.2 snapshot you need - it's the Developer snapshot.